# Where to ask about the legal / illegal behavior of software

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, legal

In case there already is a Q/A, the question is:

> What is the legal stance on software automatically copying referral links to the clipboard without user permission or prompting?

This has to do with a game, so I see this falling into legal, software dev and game dev categories. I've tried asking programming / legal questions before with much difficulty as to where to ask... any advice on how / where to ask this?

Comment: Let me also throw [security.SE] into the mix, though they'll probably get hung up on laws being different in different jurisdictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com)?

Stuff dealing with things like copyright, user rights, agreements... are all on-topic there.

Comment: That's what I had in mind to try, wanted to confirm software-related topics were relevant there. Will try there, thanks

Comment: @XerenNarcy Generally speaking, if you have an idea of a site, and you want to know if your question will work there, you can also ask on that sites meta.

Comment: Not unless you have at least 5 reputation points on that site. The association bonus will cover that, but unless you have that you can't just join a site and start posting on its meta.

Comment: @ale Well, in this case, the OP can get an association bonus/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you should ask in the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

However, you mention that you are asking about a legal aspect, when developing a game. It is also worth considering that questions concerning legality issues of game development are often also on topic over at [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com). It is not uncommon to be directed to Law; regardless, I see quite a few very useful and informed answers, in regards to legal issues encountered during game development.